# Cron job for Multisite in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, cron, multisite

I have a multisite WordPress setup with CiviCRM 4.7.23 and I am unable to create a successful cron job. I tried CLI with all parameters (including -s) and with no parameters but each time I get no output and CiviCRM says cron was not executed.

I tried the URL method

https://mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=XXX&pass=XXX&key=XXX

and same thing.

I tried, just for fun, the cli file via a browser and I got

> cli.php can only be run from command line.

which is at least correct. :)

The site in question is hosted on CiviHosting and the setup there is known to support both CLI and URL cron jobs for single-site setups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage one WordPress multisite instance, so I looked how cron is configured.

We use [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org) with the CiviCRM extension to trigger cron.

Cron jobs look like:

```
11,26,41,56 * * * * /full/path/to/wp-cli --user=civicrmcron --url=https://sitenumber7.org/ --require=/full/path/to/wp-cli/civicrm.php --path=/path/to/wordpress/webroot civicrm api --timezone=America/New_York job.execute auth=0 > /dev/null
12,27,42,57 * * * * /full/path/to/wp-cli --user=civicrmcron --url=https://sitenumber8.org/ --require=/full/path/to/wp-cli/civicrm.php --path=/path/to/wordpress/webroot civicrm api --timezone=America/Los_Angeles job.execute auth=0 > /dev/null
```

Note that if your multisite instances are in a subdirectory, rather than a different domain, you can set the URL accordingly and it still works.

Also note: Some WordPress plugins can interfere with cron!  That's not multi-site specific, but you can exclude plugins from loading with wp-cli either by specifying on the command line or creating a config file.